# How to paste an image on clipboard to the file selection dialog?

Tags: windows, images, clipboard

I have an image in my clipboard, and I am faced with a file selection dialog. Is there a way to paste that image directly to select it, so I don't have to manually open paint, save, open the dialog and then select the image?

Something like this function from SlimJet browser, but system-wide.
[image]

I know a few websites already integrate that function into their upload forms, but I would like to bake that into the system upload so I don't have to rely on the implementation of a specific website, and also use it in file selection dialogs that are not on the web.

Answer (score 0):

1. Leave the file dialog alone for a minute, and go open a web browser
2. Go to https://snag.gy in the browser and paste the clipboard to the page
3. Copy the snipboard.io link link URL it gives you
4. Go back to the file dialog and paste the URL itself into the file name selection box
5. Profit

Comment: This is the process I have been doing for years. But I wanted to directly paste the clipboard image to the file dialogue